# SAS Infile Statement Not Getting Observations

Tags: sas

I need to use the INFILE statement to read a file called np_traffic.csv, name the table traffic2, and only import a column called ReportingDate as a character.

Current Code is giving me the error

> "The data set WORK.TRAFFIC2 may be incomplete.  When this step was
>   stopped there were 0 observations and 1 variables."

[image]

```
DATA traffic2;
INFILE “E:/Documents/Week 2/np_traffic.csv”
dsd firstobs=2;
INPUT ReportingDate $;
RUN;
```

Comment: Looks like you have smart quotes.  Use single quotes.  May also need \ instead of /.

Comment: You posted a picture of a spreadsheet, but your program is trying to read a text file.  Which type of file do you actually have? Look at the file with a text editor instead of with a spreadsheet program.

Comment: You cannot read a file in this manner. You need to read all columns, I suspect, but only ReportingDate as a date or drop the other fields after. If you're uncertain of the code, first run PROC IMPORT, check the log and adapt yours as needed.

Comment: Update the question, paste in some of the lines from the actual csv file, copied from viewing the data file in Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you really have a delimited text file, which is what a CSV file is, instead of the spreadsheet you pictured in the photograph in your post.  To read the 6th field in a line you need to first read the first 5 fields. That does not mean you need use the values read from those fields.

```
data traffic2;
  infile “E:/Documents/Week 2/np_traffic.csv”
    dsd firstobs=2
  ;
  length dummy $1 ReportingDate $12;
  input 5*dummy ReportingDate ;
  drop dummy;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try it this way:

```
data traffic2;
 drop a b c d e g;
 infile 'E:\Documents\Week 2\np_traffic.csv' dsd dlm='<Insert your delimiter>' firstobs=2;
 input a b c d e f g;
run;
```

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1rill4udj0tfun1fvce3j401plo.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en